# New to gaming / having high performance display(s) in linux ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, 22.04, display

I'm sorry if this (seemingly dead) horse has been beaten more than it should (I was never in loop to begin with) but if it must be beaten once again, feel free to drop the links to the comprehensive guides about having drivers for gaming (Nvidia etc) in linux (particularly Ubuntu) and/or things I need to know/have to having high resolution and/or high refresh rate display(s) (and troubleshoot them) if it's already existing somewhere if you don't mind :)

I'm using RTX 3080 10GB, connecting to Gigabyte M28U (4K 144Hz) thru Display Port 1.4 and LG 22MP58VQ-P (1080p 60Hz) thru HDMI, and only my m28u detected (with 4k and 88hz in display setting)

what should i do, or what driver version i might need to install, etc? and how do i check what i have (driver, etc) version rn? thanks :)